# Unix subsystem for windows

Tags: windows, posix

One of the bullet point features for Windows Vista Enterprize and Ultimate is the Unix subsystem for windows, which allows you to write posix... stuff? Anyway I'm outa my league talking about it... Anyone use this feature?  Or explain it...

I know next to nothing about Unix programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably best not to try to use the Posix subsystem for Windows. It was never really complete and is just a useless marketing tick box.

If you're truly interested in programming stuff for Unix, download one of the many Linux distributions (ie. [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com)) and [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org). Install and start playing.

Comment: In addition, it's being deprecated: http://brianreiter.org/2011/09/15/sua-deprecated-in-windows-8/ .

Answer (score 4):

You might like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) for having a Linux environment on your windows machine. Otherwise, definitely go for an isolated environment (virtual machines) like the others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to discourage you from trying linux. But in this context it should be pointed out, that Linux is not completely posix compliant!

Wikipedia has a list of [fully posix compliant operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix#Fully_POSIX-compliant)

From that list, Solaris is probably the best to get started.

But anyway - for most of your posix-needs Linux should be the best choice (especially for beginners!)

Answer (score 0):

The Posix subsystem in Windows is not only incomplete, but also slower in many cases than the "native" windows functions for the same thing. This is true for I/O for example.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Cygwin mentioned by another poster you should also consider [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).